# ImageView adjustViewBounds does not seems to work??(Different project different outcome)

Tags: android, imageview

I was trying to use ImageView that would match the parent width while maintaining aspect ratio. The outcome was as expected in 1 project. But in other case, the same code gave the different result.

FYI, the layout are from two different project, not same project.Can anyone help me?

![Project 1 Layout ][1]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/news_holder" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

![Project 2 layout][2]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/news_holder" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set your targetSDK 19 it gave the expected result. But when set to 17 then problem came. And from documentation, this should be the reason.

Note from [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds(boolean)):

> If the application targets API level 17 or lower, adjustViewBounds
>   will allow the drawable to shrink the view bounds, but not grow to
>   fill available measured space in all cases. This is for compatibility
>   with legacy MeasureSpec and RelativeLayout behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:src="@drawable/news_holder" />
```

You should set a height to let know the imageview it has a height to fill.In this case 150dp but you can set whatever you need.

Comment: Thank you @xabier, but I dont think my aspect ratio of imageview will be maintained if i give a manual height.

Comment: i forgot to add scaleType.Try it,i edited the answer

Comment: Nope, not working. As I mentioned earlier, it works in one project but same code failed in another. I think, the problem is not imageview but something else.

Comment: Fixed it... When I set my targetSDK 19 it gave the expected result. But when set to 17 then problem came. And from documentation... this must be the reason.[Note: If the application targets API level 17 or lower, adjustViewBounds will allow the drawable to shrink the view bounds, but not grow to fill available measured space in all cases. This is for compatibility with legacy MeasureSpec and RelativeLayout behavior.]